# How to set UITableViewCell highlighted image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to launch a method every time when user just highlights a `cell` (doesn't select it) in `UITableView`. Could you tell me please, how is it possible to do this ?

I want to do it because I have a custom cell with a pictures on it and I want to change pictures every time when user highlights the cell.

**UPD:** By highlight I mean that user just highlights a cell and don't release the finger from it. By select I mean when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is being launched (so the user releases the finger from the cell after he presses on it)

Comment: How do they highlight a cell without selecting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you envisage the user would 'highlight' a cell rather than 'selecting' one?

In iOS (or any touch based environment really) there is no concept of just highlighting a cell rather than selecting one. The only callback you get when the user touches a cell is didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

It might be worth reading up on the [documentation on tables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) here.

**UPDATE**:

Ah OK, in that case you want to set the highlightedImage property of the cells imageView a bit like this;

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"normal_image.png"];
cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"highlighted_image.png"];
```

Comment: That's the point that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not a solution. Because I need to launch my method only when the user highlights a cell (presses on it but doesn't release the finger). And when user selects the cell (presses on it and then release his finger) didSelectRowAtIndexPath is perfect. However, I need to do some changes in cell only when this cell is highlighted (I want to change an image on it)

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand your question..you dont you want to use the method selectRowAtIndexPath?

if you want to execute a method when user select a row:

-you can use the method selectRowAtIndexPath and execute your method.

you can also create an invisible UIButton inside cell and when click in a cell you will click in button and execute your method . . .

Comment: That's the point that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not a solution. Because I need to launch my method only when the user highlights a cell (presses on it but doesn't release the finger). And when user selects the cell (presses on it and then release his finger) didSelectRowAtIndexPath is perfect. However, I need to do some changes in cell only when this cell is highlighted (I want to change an image on it)

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 6.0, *UITableViewDelegate* has 3 methods to handle cell highlighting:

```
- tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:
- tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:
- tableView:didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:
```

You should use them, like in this example:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell* cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myCellHigh"];    
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell* cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myCellUnhigh"];  
}
```